# $watch an attribute only after certain event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im learning angular and i'm trying to build a form that:

1.on-blur checks if an attribute value is unique or not.

2.if the value is not unique then it starts watching the value and gives or deletes the error on the form as the user type.

i personally think this way is more user friendly. you don't get an error while typing, but once you have the error, as you correct it , error goes away.

This is my code:

```
$scope.checkUniqueValue = function(){

    var result = true;

    for(var i=0; i < $scope.users.length; i++ ){

        if($scope.users[i].name === $scope.userName){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(result){
        $scope.error = null;
    }else{
        $scope.error = "name is not unique";

        $scope.$watch( 'userName', function() {

            $scope.checkUniqueValue();

        });

    }

    return result;
};
```

It works fine  the way it should. however when i open the developer tools in chrome i see all this errors:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22user…ned%22%5D%2C%5B%22userName%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5C%22akbar%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%...<omitted>...5D angular.js:36
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22user…me%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5C%22asghar%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20undefined%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at k.$digest (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:110:66)
    at k.$apply (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:112:173)
    at HTMLInputElement.l (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:136:370)
    at HTMLInputElement.n.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:6404)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:3179) angular.js:10023
```

I was wondering if anybody knows what these errors mean and what am i doing wrong here.since the code works, it is harder for me to find the problem that causes it.

also i was wondering if there is a better way to nest $watch inside an if statement or there are better ways to approach this without using $watch.

thank you

Comment: [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) is your friend.

Comment: is there anyway to limit the ng-change to start working only after you get the error on blur? but if there is no error on blur, ng-change remains deactivated?

Comment: Why would you want that its always great to show the errors beforehand then wait for the form to be submitted. One thing you can do is set a basic limit to the number of text entered. i.e. say you will only display error if the user has typed more than 3 charecters

Answer (score 1):

The error you get mean `Infinite $digest Loop` ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)).

Essentially this:

```
    $scope.$watch( 'userName', function() {
        $scope.checkUniqueValue();
    });
```

Will always trigger a digest loop, and watches always get an initialisation call with the new value, regardless whether that value has changed or not, so once you reach the code above

```
        $scope.checkUniqueValue();
```

will always be called, and since nothing has change you define another watch, which again will call `checkUniqueValue()`, which will set another watch... and the loop goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

you should move $watch out of function checkUniqueValue, since it does not need to reside there.